# Multiple actions Selenium with Java binding

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I Have a scenario where i have to select multiple elements by pressing Ctrl while clicking element. I am using Actions lib to build and perform. I'm using xpath to find element. And ofc IE driver which i must use.

here is my code:

```
    WebElement webElement = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, '"+id+"')]"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(context.getDriver());

    builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
            .click(webElement)
            .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
            .build()
            .perform();
```

The wierd part is sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Any idees on what im doing wrong or why it works inconvinient?

[Edit]
The above code manges to click but without holding Ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

You should try providing other element as below:

```
   builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
            .click(webElement)
           .click(webElement2)
            .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
            .build()
            .perform();
```

Then it would work.